# A `\crefmultilabelformat`command allowing `\crefstripprefix` constructs for `\cref`

Tags: subfloats, cleveref, subequations

My question is a more general (and hopefully clearer) formulation of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155292/customizing-cleveref-for-pair-of-subfigure-references-1a-and-b-instead-of-1a).

With package `cleveref`, when referencing simultaneously several labeled objects, one can either use the multiformat command `\cref`, yielding for instance **refs 1, 2 and 3**, or the range format command `\crefrange`, yielding **refs 1–3**.

If the labeled objects are 1a, 1b, 1c, the range format can be tuned with `\crefstripprefix` to remove the common prefix;

```
\crefrangelabelformat{<type>}{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}
```

yielding **refs 1a–c** instead of **refs 1a–1c**.

I would like to achieve something similar with the multiformat, that is **refs 1a, b, and c**. Unfortunately, in contrast to the above where `#1` stands for the first label of the range and `#2` stands for the last label, the `\creflabelformat` command configures labels individually (only placeholder `#1` available, the `#2` and `#3` tunes the hyperlink, juste like `#3` to `#6` above).

The output of `\cref` with a series of label is tuned by the `\crefmultiformat` command, where a placeholder `#1` appearing in its arguments stands for each label of the series, one at a time.
Is there a way to make each label first undergo a transformation, tuned by a command “`\crefmultilabelformat`” with *two* placeholders, where `#1` would stand for, say the first rendered label of the series, and `#2` would stand for each of the others?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefrangelabelformat{figure}{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\ffigbox[\textwidth]{
\begin{subfloatrow}[3]
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\quad a \quad}{\caption{a}\label{sfig:a}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\quad b \quad}{\caption{b}\label{sfig:b}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\quad c \quad}{\caption{c}\label{sfig:c}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\quad d \quad}{\caption{d}\label{sfig:d}}
\end{subfloatrow}
}{\caption{cap}\label{fig:1}}
\end{figure} 
%

\crefrange{sfig:a}{sfig:c} % renders 1a-c, juste like I want

\cref{sfig:a,sfig:b,sfig:d} % renders 1a, 1b and 1d, and I would like 1a, b, and d.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't really see the problem. Is it that the stripping command doesn't work in a definition of the multi-format?

Comment: @cfr: if you try to create automatically the cross-reference "refs 1a, b, and c" (or "figs. 1a, b, and d" in the MWE), you will see the problem: the labels in the multiformat cannot be defined in function of the other labels. It is not the the stripping command does not work, but rather that it cannot be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't need a new command, it can be done with the existing `\crefmultiformat` by using a macro to pass the prefix information from the first component to the others, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefrangelabelformat{figure}{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}

\crefmultiformat{figure}%
  {\edef\mycrefprefixinfo{#1}figs.~#2#1#3}%
  { and~#2\crefstripprefix{\mycrefprefixinfo}{#1}#3}%
  {, #2\crefstripprefix{\mycrefprefixinfo}{#1}#3}%
  {, and~#2\crefstripprefix{\mycrefprefixinfo}{#1}#3}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\ffigbox[\textwidth]{
\begin{subfloatrow}[3]
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\quad a \quad}{\caption{a}\label{sfig:a}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\quad b \quad}{\caption{b}\label{sfig:b}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\quad c \quad}{\caption{c}\label{sfig:c}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\quad d \quad}{\caption{d}\label{sfig:d}}
\end{subfloatrow}
}{\caption{cap}\label{fig:1}}
\end{figure}

\crefrange{sfig:a}{sfig:c} % renders "1a-c", just like I want.

\cref{sfig:a,sfig:b,sfig:d} % renders "1a, b, and d", just like you want.
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is perfect. You might consider putting it in the documentation. Cheers for your great package!

Comment: Thank you, however if I add another subcaption in the figure \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\quad e \quad}{\caption{e}\label{sfig:e}} and call \cref{sfig:a,sfig:b,sfig:c,sfig:e} it fails. Any ideas?